# Kivy callbacks for instanced buttons/widgets?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make some instanced buttons that will trigger the 'on_toggle_button_state' function like the KV snippet below.  I'm sure it's something simple I've overlooked, but this has stumped me for longer than I'd like to admit.

AttributeError: 'ToggleButtons' object has no attribute 'state'

```
class ToggleButtons(StackLayout):
       
    def __init__(self, *args,  **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
        conn = sqlite3.connect('players_db.db')    
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("DELETE FROM players WHERE (name IS NULL OR name  = '')") ##Remove empty entries
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM players")
        records = c.fetchall()
        records = list(filter(None, records))
           
        for i in range(0, len(records)):
            name = str(records[i])[2:-3]        
            b = ToggleButton(size_hint = (0.2, 0.2), text = name, on_state = self.on_toggle_button_state())           
            self.add_widget(b)


    def on_toggle_button_state(self, widget):
        print("toggle state: " + widget.state)
        if widget.state == "normal":
            widget.text = "OFF"
            self.count_enabled = False
        else:
            widget.text = "ON"
            self.count_enabled = True
```

KV that works for not-instanced buttons:

```
StackLayout:
    ToggleButton:
        text: "Charlie"
        on_state: root.on_toggle_button_state(self)
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In you kv file use `<ToggleButton>:` to assign the `on_state` method with `self.parent.on_toggle_button_state(self)`.

`self` is the dynamically instantiated button and parent is the `ToggleButtons` StackLayout where you have defined the `on_toggle_button_state` method.

I've modified your code a bit so I could run it without the SQL stuff. So ignore these changes.

The difference between `ToggleButton` and `<ToggleButton>` is that the first places an instance into the StackLayout - not what you want here.
And the bracket notation, defines methods & styles for each of your instances.

Please find the snippet below with the mentioned change:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
StackLayout:

<ToggleButton>:
    text: "Charlie"
    on_state: 
        self.parent.on_toggle_button_state(self)
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)

class ToggleButton(Button):
    pass

class ToggleButtons(StackLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args,  **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
        # conn = sqlite3.connect('players_db.db')    
        # c = conn.cursor()
        # c.execute("DELETE FROM players WHERE (name IS NULL OR name  = '')") ##Remove empty entries
        # c.execute("SELECT * FROM players")
        # records = c.fetchall()
        # records = list(filter(None, records))
        records = ["test1", "test2"]
        for i in range(0, len(records)):
            # name = str(records[i])[2:-3]    
            name = records[i] # just for testing
            print(name)    
            b = ToggleButton(size_hint = (0.2, 0.2), text = name, on_state = self.on_toggle_button_state)           
            self.add_widget(b)


    def on_toggle_button_state(self, widget):
        print("toggle state: " + widget.state)
        if widget.state == "normal":
            widget.text = "OFF"
            widget.count_enabled = False
        else:
            widget.text = "ON"
            widget.count_enabled = True


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ToggleButtons()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```